# Catch and Handle CasperError

Tags: casperjs

Using CasperJS how do I catch and handle CasperError?

The default appears to continue execution of the program (which does nothing but propagates the error).

These errors are logged to the console/stdout but I don't seem to see a way (from the docs) to catch and handle these errors.

Example:

```
this.fillSelectors(selector, data);
```

May produce:

> CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: form not found

I know I can check to make sure everything exists before calling, but is there a way to catch after the fact? (this applies to many other operations like `casper.click` as well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use something currently like this:

```
casper.on('error', function(msg,backtrace) {
  this.capture('./out/error.png');
  throw new ErrorFunc("fatal","error","filename",backtrace,msg);
});
```

and then I have a custom function `ErrorFunc` to process array of any warnings or a fatal error.

If you have an unsuccessful click it should throw the `casper.on('error')`.  So you can put custom code there for how you would like to handle the error.

Here's the [documentation for Casper events](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#error).

Comment: Hm, this is not working for me. I can not catch anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
        onError: function(msg, backtrace) {
            this.capture('error.png');
            throw new ErrorFunc("fatal","error","filename",backtrace,msg);
        }
    });
```

This works pretty well.
(See http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#index-1)

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete solution for who need it ^^

```
casper.on('error', function(msg, backtrace) {
    this.capture('/tmp/error.png');
    console.log('backtrace: ' + JSON.stringify(backtrace, null, 4));
    console.log('message: ' + JSON.stringify(msg, null, 4));
    console.log('check capture in /tmp/error.png');
    casper.exit(1);
})
```